# SQL: Selecting different set of columns to be displayed according to different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, pseudocode

I have six tables as set up as shown below:
[image: Tables]

Primary key: ID

Table Names: Table_1, ..., Table_6

I am having trouble in setting up the case-when statements to implement this logic:

```
select table_1.id, table_1.A,
case    
    when table_1.A = data1, then show columns B and C
    when table_1.A = data2, then show columns D, E and F
    when table_1.A = data3, then show columns B, C, D, E and F
    when table_1.A = data4, then show no columns
from table_1, ..., table_6
where
    table_1.id = table2.id and
    table_1.id = table3.id and
    table_1.id = table4.id and
    table_1.id = table5.id and
    table_1.id = table6.id and
    table1.A = <one of data1/data2/data3/data4>
```

basically, ID and column A always need to be present and B to F are conditional on data in column A.

So there are two questions: 1. Is this even possible? 2. If yes, how?

Comment: I suggest maybe combining these 6 tables into 1 logical table.

Comment: Please use modern join syntax, not SQL from 1989.

Comment: There is no possibility to show variable number of columns in sql. The best you can do is to have 4 columns in the resultset, each with the condition described by you above, but returning only 1 value at a time and nulls where no results needed.

Comment: It is possible to return 5 columns and based on the conditions values can be filled in it. Is it fine with your requirememt?

Comment: Select all columns. Filter/hide/ignore them on the client level if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN`.  Non-matching columns will be `NULL`:

```
select *
from table_1 t1 left join
     table_2 t2
     using (id) left join
     table_3 t3
     using (id) left join
     . . .;
```

If you actually want to vary the columns returned in the result set, then you need to use dynamic SQL.

If you actually want to vary the number of columns *by row*, that is impossible.  Such a result set is not a SQL result set.